# <jsp:setProperty> using value from inside a javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I need to use a variable I declare inside a javascript function for a `<jsp:setProperty>` statement.

What happens is that when the user selects an option from my drop down menu, my function is called:

```
<script>
  var selected;
  function setUnit(unit){
    selected = unit.options[unit.selectedIndex].value;
    return selected;
  }
</script>

<select name="unit" onchange="setUnit(this);">
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${bean.units}">
     <option value="${row.UNITINITIALS}" selected="selected">${row.UNITINITIALS}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And it does send the right option. What I need now is to use `selected` as the value for this:

`<jsp:setProperty property="initials" name="bean" value="${selected}"/>`

which I can't do. It doesn't read the value `selected` from the function.
Help please! I've been trying to solve this for awhile and I just can't seem to think of a solution or a workaround.

Thank you!

Comment: **JSP = server side. Javascript = client side.** I wish I could bold that more.

Comment: I've been seeing that response a lot, but I don't get how I can work around that..

Comment: If you want to change the HTML DOM, use javascript.